# Why Failed to show markdown-editor using VueSimpleMDE by CDN?

Tags: vue.js, markdown, simplemde

Why the following code failed to show the markdown-editor?

Why Failed to show markdown-editor using VueSimpleMDE by CDN?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/simplemde@1.11.2/dist/simplemde.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplemde@1.11.2/dist/simplemde.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-simplemde@0.4.6/dist/vue-simplemde.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            Vue.use(VueSimpleMDE);
        </script>
        <div id="vue-app">
            {{ content }}
            <markdown-editor v-model="content" ref="markdownEditor"></markdown-editor>
        </div>        
        <script>
            var vue = new Vue({ "el": "#vue-app", data: { content: "kdfljads" } });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Where is the `markdownEditor` component declared?

Comment: No errors in the console, the markdownEditor is a component of VueSimpleMDE.

Comment: Hmmm....  I looked at `vue-simplemde.js` and I see that is where `markdownEditor` is defined as a global component (so no need to include it in a `components` definition).  Everything looks right to me.  May have to open an issue with the vue-simplemde author.